Load a third-party script in different routes in next js
I added a third-party script (usercentrics -> https://app.usercentrics.eu/browser-ui/latest/loader.js) in the root layout of my Next 14/React project and it is working fine.
I have a module in another page contains this code:
<div class="uc-embed" uc-layout="1" uc-data="all"></div>

link to doc
The script suppose to add some content in the div tag and when user navigates to the page, the content should be there.
But the content is there only when user refresh the page and by just navigating to the page, the div tag is empty.
Next Js indicated in their doc how to add a third-party script but also indicated:

Next.js will ensure the script will only load once, even if a user
navigates between multiple routes in the same layout.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts
Another point is that a headless CMS (Storyblok) has been used in the project and the most of routes (including the page contains the code I have mentioned) and link to the page both come from the CMS.
So I want to know is there any way to load same script in two different pages in Next Js?
I resolved the issue in this dirty way but I want to know if there is a better way to make this feasible:
"use client"

import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export const UCData = () => {
  const ucRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(()=>{
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!ucRef.current?.children.length) {
        location.reload()
      }, 3000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="uc-embed" uc-data="all" ref={ucRef}></div>
  )
}


location.reload() makes your entire of your website reloaded which is not ideal.
Instead of loading your 3rd-party script on the application level, you can implement a side-effect to load your script along with uc-data element within UCData.
"use client"

import { useEffect } from 'react'

export const UCData = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = 'uc-script-src'; //replace this with your own script source
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="uc-embed" uc-data="all"></div>
  )
}

With this approach, you can completely remove the script element from the application level.

Bit late to the party, but here's what I would use:
import Script from 'next/script'

export const UCData = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        src="uc-script-src" // replace this with your own script source
        strategy="afterInteractive" // default value, change if needed
      />
      <div className="uc-embed" uc-data="all" />
    </>
  )
}

The Script component handles the script injection and should work as is, otherwise you can change the loading strategy prop. It's also possible to use in the root layout but I would only recommend doing that if you need to load the script on every route.
